# How to get each View y position with FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList`

```
render () {
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={movieData}
      renderItem={this.renderRow}
      horizontal={false}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} 
     />
  );
}
```

my `renderRow` function:

```
renderRow({ item }) {
  return (
    <View onLayout={this.getPosition.bind(this)} style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 8 }}>
       // some text...
    </View>
  );
}
```

When I try to console.log my `y` value that each item's y value shows `8`

[image]

I'm confused with it, I think `y` value should be different.

Any one knows why and how to get `y` value in my each item ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the implementation of the `getPosition` method?